# make .active class work on load on slider

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, flexslider

I have a slider which is on this site I'm working on and its using this code here to initialise the slider:

```
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery(".rslides").responsiveSlides({
    timeout: 8000,
    after: function () {
      var $active = jQuery('.banner-slider ul.slides li.rslides1_on');
      var id = $active.attr('id');
      id = id.split('_')[1];
      id = id.replace('s', '');
      id = parseInt(id, 10) + 1;
      $('ul.ui-tabs-nav li a').removeClass('active');
      $('.slidetab-' + id + ' a').addClass('active');
    }
  });
});
```

The issue seems to be, that the whole slider needs to actually rotate once before the .active is started. The URL is here: http://146.66.102.90/~amyb6060/ and you will see the slider in the header, once it fades/rotates, it gets the active colour in the box.. But it needs to rotate once before it does this.

Can anyone help me work out a way to get this to work on the site load, so that the first tab is active when the site loads.

Any help would be great :)

Comment: This is to suggest improvements as another edit is in the queue: Can you please fix some grammar?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by adding another class to load on the first block and then get it to remove itself using:

```
 $('ul.ui-tabs-nav li.slidetab-1 a').removeClass('purpleload');
```

within the function.